# Focus on the form field after submit

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

How can I focus on a particular form field after a form submission?

Things already tried:

1.

`dispatch(focus('fieldRefName'))`

2.
`componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
    if (nextProps.submitting) {
      this.refs.fieldRefname.focus()
    }
  }`

I also want to clean the form too after submission.

redux-form version: 3.0.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `focus()` action has no effect on the DOM. It's a reaction to the `onFocus` event *from* the DOM. You will need to use `this.refs.myField.focus()`.

To clean the form, after submit...

```
<form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(values => {
  return doSubmit(values).then(() => this.props.reset())
}}>
...
</form>
```

Comment: this is not working, then is not triggered.. my doSubmit method looks like: const doSubmit = (values, dispatch) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { //... some code// })}